# mongodb background task

Tags: mongodb, background

If possible, i'd like to run a find & remove query on non-indexed columns in "background", without disturbing other tasks or exhausting memory to the detriment of others.

For indexing, there is a background flag. Can the same be appended for find/remove tasks?

Thanks for a tip

Comment: Not as far as I know and also what you mean by removal of non-indexed columns? Does that mean you are not removing the whole row but instead using an in-memory operator to remove columns? Also non-indexed columns should remove as qwuick as indexed ones providing the find for the remove uses an index.

Comment: I am going to find by a non-index field e.g. .find({i_am_not_indexed:"target"}) and remove the matching documents entirely. this takes some minutes. this was OK, because it is not an urgent task, but it is slowing down the other mongo tasks. that's why i look for something like background:true..

Comment: Ah I see now, sorry I know of no way. I thought about using replicas as a method of doing priority but it wouldn't work due to the implementation of replication in MongoDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something you can use "background:true" for. Possibly the best way to handle this is to write a script that does this in the background. This script should run your operation in small batches with some delay in between. In pseudo code you would do:

- find 10 docs you need to update
- update those 10 docs
- sleep
- goto first step.

You will have to experiment with which value for sleep works. You do need to realize that all documents that you are updating need to be pulled into memory, so it will have at least some impact.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a background:true flag for this operation. The remove will yield when page faults occur and allow other operations to execute. If you need to throttle this, then you can either remove in smaller batches or use a find/remove pattern which will lower the impact to other operations.

Comment: the same happens with .find (without remove). also no workaround for this low-priority task?